# How do I make the play/pause button (F8) on my mac keyboard play/pause in the Amazon Music app

Tags: keyboard, mediaplayer

How do I make the play/pause button (F8) on my mac keyboard play/pause in the Amazon Music app.

I'm running Catalina.

I have an apple wireless keyboard. https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MQ052LL/A/magic-keyboard-with-numeric-keypad-us-english-silver?fnode=56

It has media function keys (rewind, play/pause, fastforward).

I am currently listening to music on Amazon Music. (https://www.amazon.com/b?node=16962657011)

Right now, when I press the play/pause button, it launches [Apple] Music.

How do I make it so that pressing play/pause affects Amazon Music?

Answer (score 1):

[This](https://www.jonathan.vc/tech/2016/06/change-default-play-button-mac-support-3rd-party-apps) article suggests using [Magic Keys](https://www.gearmusicplayer.com/extras.html) to reroute media keys to third party applications.

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm hoping for something in the OS that can handle this, but the existence of this software implies that the OS can't handle it. However, I'm already using [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) so, perhaps I'll look into that.